# logical operators and if statements combination

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm looking if there is an alternative to write this code cleaner and efficient.
My goal is to set different values based on the hour of the day.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var user = 'User4';

if (hour >= 4 && hour < 6) {
    user = 'User1';
}
if (hour >= 6 && hour < 13) {
    user = 'User2';
}
if (hour >= 13 && hour < 19) {
    user = 'User3';
}
if (hour >= 19) {
    user = 'User4';
}
```

I found [this article](https://blog.wax-o.com/2015/05/an-alternative-to-if-else-and-switch-in-javascript/) online, but I couldn't achieve logical operators into this.

```
let values = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
};
let foo = values[ bar ] || 3;
```

Really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `else if` to make code shorter and cleaner

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var user;

if (hour < 4 || hour >= 19) {
  user = 'User4';
} else if (hour < 6) {
  user = 'User1';
} else if (hour < 13) {
  user = 'User2';
} else if (hour < 19) {
  user = 'User3';
}

console.log(user)
```

Using **switch(true)**

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var user;

switch(true) {
  case (hour < 4 || 
        hour >= 19): user = 'User4'; break;
  case (hour < 6)  : user = 'User1'; break;
  case (hour < 13) : user = 'User2'; break;
  case (hour < 19) : user = 'User3'; break;
}

console.log(user)
```

Comment: The article they shared was listing alternative to if-else and switch in JavaScript, so i'm not really sure if this helps.

Comment: @Saurav But how could you achieve this with the object literal? He is asking for alternative and cleaner solution

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean using objects here but, but if bar=a. User will get the value as 1. That's simply using a JavaScript OR operator, if bar is assigned to nothing, obj[bar] will return nothing and the value of user will get assigned as 3.

Answer (score 1):

What about using conditional operators

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var user = 'User4'

user=(hour >= 4 && hour < 6)?'User1': (hour >= 6 && hour < 13)?'User2':(hour >= 13 && hour < 19)?'User3':(hour >= 19)?'User4':''
console.log(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to do it by ternary operators, you can try

```
let user = hour <13? (hour >= 6 && hour < 13)? "User 2" : "User 1" : (hour >= 13 && hour < 19)? "User 3" : "User 4"
```

This should be the simplest way to achieve the desired result, however you may continue with your own example and do something like

```
let values = {
    a: "User 1",
    b: "User 2",
    c: "User 3",
    d: "User 4"
};


let bar = hour <13? (hour >= 6 && hour < 13)? "b" : "a" : (hour >= 13 && hour < 19)? "c" : "d"

let foo = values[ bar ] || 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what @Asaf is asking but if he want something like below one

```
let values = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
};
let foo = values[ bar ] || 3;
```

he can try something  like this (This is not prefered way to do)

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
let values = {
  4 : 'User1',
  5 : 'User1',
  6 : 'User2',
  7 : 'User2',
  8 : 'User2',
  9 : 'User2',
  10 : 'User2',
  11 : 'User2',
  12 : 'User2',
  13 : 'User3',
  14 : 'User3',  
  15 : 'User3',  
  16 : 'User3',  
  17 : 'User3',  
  18 : 'User3',  
};
let foo = values[ hour ] || 'User4';
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write this as an object, you need to list all 24 hours, making the code simpler, but longer:

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var name = 'User';
var id = {
   0: 4,
   1: 4,
   2: 4,
   3: 4,
   4: 1,
   5: 1,
   6: 2,
   7: 2,
   8: 2,
   9: 2,
  10: 2,
  11: 2,
  12: 2,
  13: 3,
  14: 3,
  15: 3,
  16: 3,
  17: 3,
  18: 3,
  19: 4,
  20: 4,
  21: 4,
  22: 4,
  23: 4
};
var user = name + id[ hour];
console.log(user);
```

As mentioned in the article you linked, I feel this is one of those logic blocks where ternaries make things ugly.

So personally i would prefer the if/else version below since its the most readable as if it were 'plain english'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that doesn't use `if` or `switch`:

```
var periods = [
  { from: 0, to: 4, user: 'User4' },
  { from: 4, to: 6, user: 'User1' },
  { from: 6, to: 13, user: 'User2' },
  { from: 13, to: 19, user: 'User3' },
  { from: 19, to: 23, user: 'User4' }
]; 

var hour = new Date().getHours();
var user = periods.find(p => hour >= p.from && hour < p.to).user;
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [Code golf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) point of view, chaining the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) could be the shortest method.
But it doesn't help with the readability if it's used in one long line.
But a bit of code indentation helps.

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();

var user = (hour >= 4 && hour <= 5 ? "User1"
          : hour >= 6 && hour <= 12 ? "User2"
          : hour >= 13 && hour <= 18 ? "User3"
          : hour >= 19 ? "User4"
          : "User4");

console.log(hour, user);
```

Or this shorter version:

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();

var user = (hour < 4 || hour > 18 ? "User4"
          : hour < 6 ? "User1"
          : hour < 13 ? "User2"
          : "User3");

console.log(hour, user);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the conditions inside of an own function for getting the user and return early if the condition match.

```js
function getUser(hour) {
    if (hour < 4) return 'User4';
    if (hour < 6) return 'User1';
    if (hour < 13) return 'User2';
    if (hour < 19) return 'User3';
    return 'User4';
}

var hour = new Date().getHours(),
    user = getUser(hour);

console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is fine and is efficient. An alternative approach you could take is a functional one, where you define each range using a function like so:

```js
const hour = new Date().getHours();
const I = x => x;
const K = x => y => x;
const setRange = (x, y, out) => (f, h) => f(h >= x && h < y)(out);
const createRanges = (...ranges) => def => h => {
  for(const rf of ranges) 
    if(rf(K, h)) return rf(K(I), h);
  return def;
}

const getUser = createRanges(
  setRange(4, 6, 'User1'),
  setRange(6, 13, 'User2'),
  setRange(13, 19, 'User3')
)("User4"); // default/else "User 4"
const user = getUser(hour);

console.log(hour, user);
```